# Create and Update actions, is this good style?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am updating a user object, but before the save/update I need to perform some parsing on a property of the object, do I have to repeat it or should I be using a filter to do this before the save?

example:

```
def create
   @user = User.new(params[:user]

   @user.parsed_bio = parse_bio(@user.bio)

   if @user.save
      ...
   end
end

def update
   @user = User.find(params[:id])

   if @user.update_attributes(params[:user])
   ...
   end

end
```

The parsed_bio property isn't updated via the params, I have to do it explicilty.

**Should I just be repeating the assignment in both the create and update, or can I do this in a single place using a filter somehow?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could do it in the User's model:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  before_save :parse_bio

  private
  def parse_bio
    # parse your self.bio here
  end
end
```

Comment: great that makes sense, it removes the logic from the controller to a more centralized place!

Comment: Ya, it is a callback method. There are many other callbacks, like `before_validate, before_create, after_save, ......`. You could take a look at here: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Callbacks.html

Comment: And they would be called automatically :D